# Error 502 al ejecutar un Stored Procedure en MariaDB desde una aplicación usando el framework Laravel

Tags: laravel, mariadb, nginx, centos

Tengo un SP en una base de datos MariaDB que invocó desde una aplicación web usando Laravel de la siguiente forma:

```
$menus = DB::select('call usp_ObtenerModulo("' . $mail . '")');
```

Se ejecuta en un servidor con CentOS con Nginx y MaríaDB, y al momento de ejecutarse la página arroja

> error 502.

Esta mismo programa funciona correctamente en servidores Windows con XAMP.

Esta es la configuración del Virtual Hosts:

```
listen 80;

root /usr/share/nginx/MiniERP/public;
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
access_log /usr/share/nginx/MiniERP/logs/access.log;
error_log /usr/share/nginx/MiniERP/logs/error.log error;

server_name minierp.bizengine.mx;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}


location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}

location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
     access_log        off;
     log_not_found     off;
     expires           30d;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all; access_log off; log_not_found off;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

client_max_body_size 100m;
```

Y esto es mi configuración del NGINX

; DESPUES

```
user = nginx
group = nginx

; The address on which to accept FastCGI requests.
; Valid syntaxes are:
;   'ip.add.re.ss:port'    - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv4 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   '[ip:6:addr:ess]:port' - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv6 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   'port'                 - to listen on a TCP socket to all addresses
;                            (IPv6 and IPv4-mapped) on a specific port;
;   '/path/to/unix/socket' - to listen on a unix socket.
; Note: This value is mandatory.
; MODIFICACION DE DAVID, ANTES
; listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
; AHORA
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock

; Set listen(2) backlog.
; Default Value: 511 (-1 on FreeBSD and OpenBSD)
;listen.backlog = 511

; Set permissions for unix socket, if one is used. In Linux, read/write
; permissions must be set in order to allow connections from a web server. Many
; BSD-derived systems allow connections regardless of permissions.
; Default Values: user and group are set as the running user
;                 mode is set to 0660
; MODIFICACION DE DAVID
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0660
; When POSIX Access Control Lists are supported you can set them using
; these options, value is a comma separated list of user/group names.
; When set, listen.owner and listen.group are ignored
;listen.acl_users =
;listen.acl_groups =
```

Estos son los procesos que están corriendo antes de ejecutar el procedimiento que invoca al Stored Procedure:

900 root      20   0  425m 4176  936 S  0.0  0.1   0:08.71 php-fpm

```
10394 nginx     20   0  430m  45m  38m S  0.0  1.1   0:05.67 php-fpm
10396 nginx     20   0  435m  50m  37m S  0.0  1.2   0:33.15 php-fpm
10398 nginx     20   0  429m  45m  38m S  0.0  1.1   0:05.82 php-fpm
10412 nginx     20   0  429m  42m  35m S  0.0  1.0   0:06.11 php-fpm
10509 nginx     20   0  432m  46m  37m S  0.0  1.1   0:05.73 php-fpm
10511 nginx     20   0  499m 112m  37m S  0.0  2.8   0:27.87 php-fpm
10513 nginx     20   0  432m  48m  37m S  0.0  1.2   0:27.38 php-fpm
10519 nginx     20   0  429m  43m  36m S  0.0  1.1   0:05.58 php-fpm
11563 nginx     20   0  430m  42m  32m S  0.0  1.0   0:09.86 php-fpm
11565 nginx     20   0  431m  44m  35m S  0.0  1.1   0:03.95 php-fpm
```

Este es el error que se genera al ejecutarse el SP

```
2018/08/19 18:24:32 [error] 880#0: *5309 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 200.68.136.141, server: minierp.bizengine.mx, request: "GET /index HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock:", host: "minierp.bizengine.mx", referrer: "http://minierp.bizengine.mx/"
```

Este es el log que se generó en el log del php-fpm:

```
[19-Aug-2018 18:24:32] WARNING: [pool www] child 11563 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 87712.473751 seconds from start
[19-Aug-2018 18:24:32] NOTICE: [pool www] child 19640 started
```

Estos son los permisos de sock

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root     3 Aug 16 13:40 php-fpm.pid
srw-rw----  1 nginx nginx    0 Aug 16 13:40 php-fpm.sock
```

Comment: Podrías agregar tus configuraciones de nginx en la pregunta? para ver si es posible ayudar.

Comment: @JulioLago listo

Comment: está corriendo el fpm? -> `$ ps aux | grep php` , que cuenta el error log de ngingx? -> `$ tail  /usr/share/nginx/MiniERP/logs/error.log` y el error log de fpm? -> `$ tail /var/log/syslog` , por último vería que onda los permisos del sock `$ ls -al /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock`

Comment: @aloMalbarez ya agregué lo que solicitas, gracias!

Comment: humm no da muchas pistas =P, en un tiempo newrelic daba errores de ese tipo. (php-fpm está crasheando) una forma es ir desactivando extensiones para ver cual es la que rompe todo, aunque también puede ser permisos en la carpeta de sesiones `$ ls -ld /var/lib/php/session`, o poco espacio en disco `$ df -h`

Comment: ademas de newrelic fijate si apc o memcached están instalados (si se quedan sin memoria hacen volcar el fpm)

Comment: Ya se resolvió, le tuve que agrega los siguientes parámetros al database.php:  'options' => [\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_COMPRESS => true,]